# tengo problema en login json php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

estoy confuso entre json y jquery me da [objet][objet] 
la verdad no lose 
les paso el codigo

```js
//tema es ajax json 
function iniciar_sesion(user, password) {
    var validaruser = user.split(" ").join("");
    var validarpass = password.split(" ").join("");
    if (validaruser == '' || validarpass == '') {
        $('#rsp').text('Completa los campos');
        $('#alert').slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlWeb + 'inc/test.php',
            data: $('#cgi_login').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(respuestaloguin) {
                alert(respuestaloguin);
                if (respuestaloguin == 'error') {
                    $('#rsp').text('Datos incorrectos');
                    $('#alert').slideDown(500);
                } else if (respuestaloguin == 'yes') {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
// php anda todo bien   
<?php require("../Connections/Conexion.php");
$user = $_REQUEST['inpuser'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
  
   mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
 $query_DatosLogin =  sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s OR email=%s AND password=%s",
 GetSQLValueString($user, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString(($pass), "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($user, "text"),
 GetSQLValueString(($pass), "text"));
 $DatosLogin = mysql_query($query_DatosLogin, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
 $row_DatosLogin = mysql_fetch_assoc($DatosLogin);
 $totalRows_DatosLogin = mysql_num_rows($DatosLogin);
if($totalRows_DatosLogin==1){
$data = array("success" => true);
}else{
$data = array("success" => false);
}
echo json_encode($data);


 ?>
```

Comment: puedes hacer un console.log de respuestaloguin

Answer (score 2):

Como respuesta del proceso estas devolviendo un array en JSON, por ende deberias tratarlo como un array y no como una variable. Ademas de esto, estabas validando que la respuesta sea "error" o "yes" y ninguno de estos valores esta definido en PHP.

```
success: function(respuestaloguin) {
                alert(respuestaloguin.success);
                if (respuestaloguin.success == false) {
                    $('#rsp').text('Datos incorrectos');
                    $('#alert').slideDown(500);
                } else{
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
```